# I am trying to display store which has been open at least two hours before current time

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-arithmetic

whose table is

```
CREATE TABLE TOY_STORE
(
    TOY_STORE_ID        NUMBER(3)       PRIMARY KEY,
    TOY_STORE_NAME      VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
    CITY                VARCHAR2(30)    DEFAULT 'Delhi',
    PHONENUMBER         NUMBER(10)      UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    STORE_OPENING_TIME  TIMESTAMP       CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STORE_OPENING_TIME)>=8),
    STORE_CLOSING_TIME  TIMESTAMP       CHECK(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STORE_CLOSING_TIME)<22)
);
```

and there is some problem in following code. can anyone correct it plz

```
SELECT  TOY_STORE_NAME 
FROM    TOY_STORE 
WHERE 
(
    SELECT  EXTRACT (HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-STORE_OPENING_TIME) 
    FROM    TOY_STORE
)>=2;
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? It would be helpful if you would edit your question and include some sample data, the results you're getting, and the results you expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the difference between two date/time values we use the INTERVAL datatype.  So your query might look like this:

```
select TOY_STORE_NAME
from TOY_STORE
where ( localtimestamp - STORE_OPENING_TIME) >= interval '2' hour
/
```

Of course that's wrong.  Because STORE_OPENING_TIME is a `timestamp` it contains a date.  So you have correctly twigged that you need to extract the hour element from the timestamp.  The snag is that you need to convert it into an interval too.  We can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL()` for that.

So, to find stores which have been open for at least two hours what you need is something like this

```
select TOY_STORE_NAME
from TOY_STORE
where NUMTODSINTERVAL(extract(hour from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'Hour')  
       >= NUMTODSINTERVAL(extract(hour from STORE_OPENING_TIME)+2, 'Hour')
/
```

Now we have intervals on both sides of the WHERE clause.

Note that using a TIMESTAMP to represent a time without a date *will* cause problems at some point, as the intention is easy to misunderstand.  A better solution would be to store the times as a string, say 'HH24:MI', and use date arithmetic to handle it.  For instance,

```
select TOY_STORE_NAME
from TOY_STORE
where to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||STORE_OPENING_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') 
                 + NUMTODSINTERVAL(2, 'Hour')  >= sysdate
/
```

I agree it looks ugly but it can be wrapped in a user-defined function.

Much of this pain would be avoided if Oracle SQL had a TIME datatype (that is, without the date element), but alas it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here first you retrieve time from timestamp fields by trunc(). Then comparing time difference with interval of 2 hours will help you retrieve names of store open for atleast 2 hours before current time.

```
select TOY_STORE_NAME
from TOY_STORE       
where (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - (STORE_OPENING_TIME-trunc(STORE_OPENING_TIME)) >= interval '2' hour;
```